# modify a property of a component through a controller in emberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I wonder if I can modify a property that is in a component via an external controller.

That is, I have an injected component in index.html as follows:
`{{ button-feed }}`

This component is used in many views.

This component has to be hidden as I get values in the controller, and what I really want is that since this controller, modify a property that hides or shows the button.

The component has the form:

```
App.ButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend ({
   hideClass: false
});
```

The property `hideClass` is used to display or not the button. What I want is to modify this property but using a controller that does not belong to the component button.

I tried to access the property from outside the component, but it is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to your component like this:

```
{{button-feed hideClass=true}}
{{button-feed hideClass=false}}
```

Also, you could pass in a controller property too.

```
{{button-feed hideClass=controllerProperty}}
```

To answer your comment, you can set the `controllerProperty` by using the code below.  Since `controllerProperty` is bound to the `hideClass` on your component, changing `controllerProperty` will change `hideClass`.

```
controller.set('controllerProperty', false);
```

You can read more about setting properties on a controller [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_set).

Comment: Yes, but how could I update the property 'hideClass' from controller?
Sorry, I'm newbie :P